# # Buildozer failed to execute the last command #

Tags: python, android, linux, ubuntu, buildozer

Can anyone please resolve my issue I am using buildozer on a linux virtual machine to convert a .py file to apk for my android mobile

This is my first kivy project and i really need some help to make it possible

This is the code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

if __name__ in ('__android__', '__main__'):
    MyApp().run()
```

It is a preety simple one that displays a button saying hello world

When I use buildozer android debug it returns me this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 5a94d074 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2244 from Chronolife-team/native_services_upstream
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'toml\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19c
# Android NDK found at /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=Newzac --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21'
# Cwd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py:84: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 694, in __init__
    self.ctx.setup_dirs(self.storage_dir)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 173, in setup_dirs
    raise ValueError('storage dir path cannot contain spaces, please '
ValueError: storage dir path cannot contain spaces, please specify a path with --storage-dir
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=Newzac --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ubuntu2004:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1734,unix/ubuntu2004:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1734'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1628'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Lunar Aplocon'
#     LOGNAME = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/ubuntu'
#     USERNAME = 'ubuntu'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/c51b243c_61ea_40b5_8d21_7ae9872461c6'
#     INVOCATION_ID = 'a6f15881930a4d0284aae1df91941ec2'
#     MANAGERPID = '1449'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.218'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=fa17123d1ef28ed988e7c66f5fdc433c'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:53552'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=fa17123d1ef28ed988e7c66f5fdc433c'
#     _ = '/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: At which phase does it fail? Please include the output before the error, or a part of it if it's too long

Comment: @Shar i have edited the question and given the full output on the command terminal kindly help me out to solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have your files in a directory named `'Lunar Aplocon'`. The space `' '` in the file name is causing the issue. Even when you enter the name in your buildozer.sec file try not to include any space (you can include in title but not in org and other info). So you just have to rename your directory then it will be just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much this has solved my problem.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind then accept the answer as correct (By clicking on that check mark)

Comment: Sure. Your response was very helpful for me.